# Issue with Apache and virtual host config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf

So I have two web sites hosted on the same server and same IP address.  Ok no biggie.  I setup my `httpd.conf` file in a way I believe is correct.  The first site, `cascocc.com` works no problem.  The second site `coloradospringshomebuilders.com` is the problem.  It redirects to `http://coloradospringshomebuilders.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` and the `www` alias does not work.  Below is what I think are the relevant parts for my config file with the rest in a paste bin below.  I have also included the `.htaccess` files below as well too.  Any ideas?

I am getting a 403 forbidden error any time i try to access anything in the document root.  How do I correct this

[http.conf file can be found here](http://pastebin.com/nE7mzD3H)

[.htaccess file for coloradospringshomebuilders.com](http://pastebin.com/Lp77SSn0)

[.htaccess file for cascocc.com](http://pastebin.com/HBk22jQ3)

```
    <VirtualHost 216.172.182.170:80>
    ServerName 216.172.182.170
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin root@cas.cascocc.com
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>


# Default vhost for unbound IPs

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName cas.cascocc.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin root@cas.cascocc.com
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost><VirtualHost 216.172.182.170:80>
        ServerName cascocc.com
        ServerAlias www.cascocc.com
        DocumentRoot /home/cascocc/public_html
        ServerAdmin xxx@cascocc.com
        UseCanonicalName Off
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/cascocc.com combined
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/cascocc.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
        <IfModule itk.c>
            # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
            #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
            AssignUserID cascocc cascocc
        </IfModule>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/cascocc/public_html/cgi-bin/




        # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
        # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/cascocc/cascocc.com/*.conf"
    </VirtualHost>

    # DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE PLEASE USE THE INCLUDE FILES.

    <VirtualHost 216.172.182.170:80>
        ServerName coloradospringshomebuilders.com
        ServerAlias www.coloradospringshomebuilders.com
        DocumentRoot /home/cascohomes/public_html
        ServerAdmin xxx@coloradospringshomebuilders.com
        UseCanonicalName Off
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/coloradospringshomebuilders.com combined
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/coloradospringshomebuilders.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
        <IfModule itk.c>
            # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
            #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
            AssignUserID cascohomes cascohomes
        </IfModule>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/cascohomes/public_html/cgi-bin/




        # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
        # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/cascohomes/coloradospringshomebuilders.com/*.conf"
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It seems you missed `NameVirtualHost *:80` in http.conf, if you haven't do that in other conf files.

Comment: I edited that out for brevity but it is in the full config file as can be seen in the paste bin as noted.  I added the wildcards to the main post for clarity